# Derby Metastore directory is created in spark workspace

Tags: apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have spark 2.1.0 installed and integrated with eclipse and hive2 installed and metastore configured in Mysql also placed hive-site.xml file in spark >> conf folder. I'm trying to access tables already present in hive from eclipse.
when I execute the program metastore folder and derby.log file is been created in spark workspace and eclipse console show the below INFO:

```
Setting MetaStore object pin classes with hive.metastore.cache.pinobjtypes="Table,StorageDescriptor,SerDeInfo,Partition,Database,Type,FieldSchema,Order"
17/06/13 18:26:43 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/06/13 18:26:43 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/06/13 18:26:43 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MFieldSchema" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/06/13 18:26:43 INFO Datastore: The class "org.apache.hadoop.hive.metastore.model.MOrder" is tagged as "embedded-only" so does not have its own datastore table.
17/06/13 18:26:43 INFO Query: Reading in results for query "org.datanucleus.store.rdbms.query.SQLQuery@0" since the connection used is closing
17/06/13 18:26:43 INFO MetaStoreDirectSql: Using direct SQL, underlying DB is MYSQL
```

spark can't able to locate the configured mysql metastore database

also throwing the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Error while instantiating 'org.apache.spark.sql.hive.HiveSessionState':
```

Code:

```
import org.apache.spark.SparkContext, org.apache.spark.SparkConf
import com.typesafe.config._
import org.apache.spark.sql.Row
import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession

object hivecore {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {

val warehouseLocation = "hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/user/hive/warehouse"

val spark = SparkSession
  .builder().master("local[*]")
  .appName("hivecore")
  .config("spark.sql.warehouse.dir", warehouseLocation)
  .enableHiveSupport()
  .getOrCreate()

import spark.implicits._
import spark.sql

sql("SELECT * FROM sample.source").show()

}
}
```

Build.sbt

```
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0" 
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.42"
```

NOTE : I can able to access the hive tables from Spark-shell

Thanks

Comment: How do you trigger the spark job from ECLIPSE?

setMaster("...") should not be 'local'; and should point to application-master.

Comment: Make a jar out of it; and invoke it using `spark submit ...`. This way, you will get the expected result.

Comment: @RaktotpalBordoloi I'm running it  in localhost, I gave like local[*]

Comment: @RaktotpalBordoloi, I just added hive-site.xml file to the resource folder of eclipse now its pointing to MYSQL but with some errors, please have a look on the Updated question

Comment: Can you share the dependency matrix for spark-core and spark-hive?? @Vickyster

Comment: libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "com.typesafe" % "config" % "1.3.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "org.apache.spark" % "spark-hive_2.11" % "2.1.0"
libraryDependencies += "mysql" % "mysql-connector-java" % "5.1.42"

Comment: @RaktotpalBordoloi, I have added my code, please have a look and let me know if there is any error or I can go with creating a jar out of it.

Comment: I think, everything looks good. Try once with creating jar and submit it through `spark-submit` command.

Comment: Ohh... One moment!!! 

Initialize HiveContext like `hc = HiveContext(sc)`

and invoke query as `hc.sql(".....")`

Comment: @RaktotpalBordoloi, I'm not sure about the directory path val warehouseLocation = "hdfs://HADOOPMASTER:54310/user/hive/warehouse" is it correct ?

Comment: That line of code is not required - as those config are already defined by `hive-site.xml`.

Main error is in `sql(....)` line - where you are using `SQLCONTEXT` to trigger the query.

Use `HIVECONTEXT` to trigger the same.

Comment: @RaktotpalBordoloi Same error persisting..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you put `context.setMaster(local)`, it may not look for the spark configurations that you setup in cluster; specially when you trigger it from ECLIPSE.

Make a jar out of it; and trigger from cmd as `spark-submit --class <main class package> --master spark://207.184.161.138:7077 --deploy-mode client`

The master ip: `spark://207.184.161.138:7077` should be replace with your cluster's ip and spark port.

And, remember to initialize HiveContext to trigger query on underlying HIVE.

```
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)
hc.sql("SELECT * FROM ...")
```

Comment: Thank you so much I got it by Adding core-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml file along with the hive-site.xml in eclipse resource folder.!